# What should be the bit-rate & sample-rate settings, if I were to convert a WebM audio file to MP3?

Tags: audio, mp3, sample-rate, encoding, bitrate

I want to convert a WebM audio file to an mp3 file using FFmpeg. I was wondering what should be the ideal bit-rate & sample rate settings for the following input.

```
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'v.webm':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : google
  Duration: 00:11:29.98, start: -0.007000, bitrate: 146 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
```

Comment: "Ideal" is not a word that will give you one answer. There is no ideal. What is it you want out - good quality, small file size, etc? mp3 is all about tradeoffs.How much loss are you prepared to accept? Depending on the type of music and your preferences, there could be any number of settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The audio is encoded using opus, which is a high quality codec. When decoding from Opus, you will likely want to go via PCM - 16 bit at 48000. The more significant parameter with mp3 encoding will be the output bitrate, which will depend on the quality you want to receive in the encoded mp3 file. if you want highest possibly quality, go 320 kb/s. Depending on the type of music or audio involved, you can go as low as 128kb/s, but 256 is a good compromise.